# Set Background Color For Part Of Label iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Is it possible to set the background color for parts of a label?  I'm trying to create something similar to the tags section at the bottom of this post that word wraps and char wraps when necessary.  Also, the text blocks can be multiple words.  Basically I need something like:

```
[label setBackgroundColor:UIColor forRange:NSRange];
```

I need to support iOS 5.0+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to get it working using NSAttributedString.  Here's my solution.  It's not super clean, but it works okay.  Phrases is an array of NSStrings.  Each phrase can be a single word or multiple words.

```
-(void)addBackgroundsToContainer:(UIView*)container color:(UIColor*)color phrases:(NSArray*)phrases {
    CGFloat x = 0.0;
    CGFloat y = 0.0;
    UIView *lbl;

    for(NSString *phrase in phrases) {
        NSLog(@"Phrase: '%@'", phrase);
        NSArray *words = [phrase componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *text = @"";

        for(int i = 0; i < words.count; i++) {
            NSString *word = [words objectAtIndex:i];
            CGSize wordSize = [word sizeWithFont:[self labelFont]];
            CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[self labelFont]];

            //if the word appended with the new text fits on one line, concatenate the two
            if(textSize.width + wordSize.width + x < container.frame.size.width) {
                text = [text isEqualToString:@""] ? word : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", text, word];

                if(i == words.count -1 ) {//add the label if it's the last word
                    lbl = [self addLabelWithX:x y:y container:container color:color text:text];
                    x = lbl.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.origin.x + 1.0;
                    text = @"";
                }

            //if the word fits on one line but can't fit on the current line.
            } else if(wordSize.width < container.frame.size.width) {
                //if it's not the first word, add the text that came before it
                if(i != 0) {
                    lbl = [self addLabelWithX:x width:container.frame.size.width - x y:y container:container color:color text:text];
                }

                x = 0.0;
                y = lbl.frame.size.height + lbl.frame.origin.y + 1.0;
                text = word;

                //if it's the last word
                if(i == words.count - 1) {
                    lbl = [self addLabelWithX:x y:y container:container color:color text:text];
                    x = lbl.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.origin.x + 1.0;
                    text = @"";
                }

            //if the word doesn't fit on one line and it 
            } else if(wordSize.width > container.frame.size.width) {
                //I don't need to do char wrapping, but this would be where it'd go

            } 
        }
    }
}

-(UIView*)addLabelWithX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y container:(UIView*)container color:(UIColor*)color text:(NSString*)text {
    CGFloat width = [text sizeWithFont:[self labelFont]].width + 4.0;
    return [self addLabelWithX:x width:width y:y container:container color:color text:text];
}
-(UIView*)addLabelWithX:(CGFloat)x width:(CGFloat)width y:(CGFloat)y container:(UIView*)container color:(UIColor*)color text:(NSString*)text {
    CGFloat lineHeight = [@" " sizeWithFont:[self labelFont]].height;

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 0.0, width, lineHeight)];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [lbl setText:text];
    [lbl setFont:[self labelFont]];

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, lbl.frame.size.height)];
    [v setBackgroundColor:color];
    [v addSubview:lbl];
    [container addSubview:v];

    return v;
}
-(UIFont*)labelFont {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:12.0];
}
```

EDIT: I went back and made this less terrible
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol WATagCloudDelegate;

@interface WATagCloud : UIView
@property(weak, nonatomic) id<WATagCloudDelegate> delegate;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataTags;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIColor *tagColor;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIFont *tagFont;

-(void)expand;
-(void)expandWithAnimation;
-(void)collapse;
-(void)collapseWithAnimation;
@end


@protocol WATagCloudDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)tagCloudExpandDown:(WATagCloud*)tagCloud;
-(void)tagCloudCollapseDown:(WATagCloud*)tagCloud;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "WATagCloud.h"
#import "WAControlsUtility.h"

@interface WATagCloud()
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIButton *btnToggleVisibility;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIView *vExpand;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UILabel *lblExpand;
@end

@implementation WATagCloud
@synthesize dataTags = _dataTags;
@synthesize tagColor = _tagColor;
@synthesize tagFont = _tagFont;
@synthesize btnToggleVisibility;
@synthesize vExpand;
@synthesize lblExpand;

-(void)setTagColor:(UIColor *)color {
    _tagColor = color;
    [self setColorOfSubviews];
}
-(void)setDataTags:(NSArray *)tags {
    _dataTags = tags;
    [self addTags];
}
-(UIFont*)tagFont {
    if(_tagFont) {
        return _tagFont;
    } else {
        _tagFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:14.0];
        return _tagFont;
    }
}
-(void)setTagFont:(UIFont *)font {
    _tagFont = font;
    [self addTags];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setClipsToBounds:YES];

        self.btnToggleVisibility = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.btnToggleVisibility setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        [self.btnToggleVisibility addTarget:self action:@selector(onToggleVisibilityDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:self.btnToggleVisibility];

        self.vExpand = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [self addSubview:self.vExpand];

        self.lblExpand = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [self.lblExpand setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.lblExpand setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.vExpand addSubview:self.lblExpand];
    }
    return self;
}

//======================================================================
//LAYOUT LABELS
//======================================================================
-(void)addTags {
    [self clearTags];
    CGFloat x = 0.0;
    CGFloat y = 0.0;
    UIView *lbl;

    for(int j = 0; j < self.dataTags.count; j++) {
        NSString *tag = [self.dataTags objectAtIndex:j];
        NSArray *words = [tag componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *text = @"";

        for(int i = 0; i < words.count; i++) {
            NSString *word = [words objectAtIndex:i];
            CGSize wordSize = [word sizeWithFont:self.tagFont];
            CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:self.tagFont];

            if(textSize.width + wordSize.width + x < self.frame.size.width) {//if the word appended with the new text fits on one line, concatenate the two
                text = [text isEqualToString:@""] ? word : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", text, word];

                if(i == words.count -1 ) {//add the label if it's the last word
                    lbl = [self addLabelWithX:x y:y text:text tag:j];
                    x = lbl.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.origin.x + 1.0;
                    text = @"";
                }


            } else if(wordSize.width < self.frame.size.width) {//if the word fits on one line but can't fit on the current line.
                //if it's not the first word, add the text that came before it
                if(i != 0) {
                    lbl = [self addLabelWithX:x width:self.frame.size.width - x y:y text:text tag:j];
                }

                x = 0.0;
                y = lbl.frame.size.height + lbl.frame.origin.y + 1.0;
                text = word;

                //if it's the last word
                if(i == words.count - 1) {
                    lbl = [self addLabelWithX:x y:y text:text tag:j];
                    x = lbl.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.origin.x + 1.0;
                    text = @"";
                }

            } else if(wordSize.width > self.frame.size.width) {//if the word doesn't fit on one line 
                NSArray *characters = [self getCharacterArrayFromString:word];  
            }
        }
    }

    //update the frame height
    [self setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:self.frame withX:nil y:nil width:nil height:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[WAControlsUtility getHeightOfView:self]]]];
    [self.btnToggleVisibility setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

//======================================================================
//ADD TO CONTAINER
//======================================================================
-(UIView*)addLabelWithX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y text:(NSString*)text tag:(int)tag {
    CGFloat width = [text sizeWithFont:[self tagFont]].width + 4.0;
    return [self addLabelWithX:x width:width y:y text:text tag:tag];
}
-(UIView*)addLabelWithX:(CGFloat)x width:(CGFloat)width y:(CGFloat)y text:(NSString*)text tag:(int)tag {
    CGFloat lineHeight = [@" " sizeWithFont:[self tagFont]].height;

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 0.0, width, lineHeight)];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [lbl setText:text];
    [lbl setFont:[self tagFont]];

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, lbl.frame.size.height)];
    [v setBackgroundColor:self.tagColor];
    [v setTag:tag];
    [v addSubview:lbl];
    [self addSubview:v];

    return v;
}

//======================================================================
//UI EVENTS
//======================================================================
-(void)onToggleVisibilityDown:(id)sender {
    if(self.delegate ==nil)
        return;

    if(self.frame.size.height > [@" " sizeWithFont:[self tagFont]].height * 2.0 + 2) {//plus 2 for the spacing between lines
        [self.delegate tagCloudCollapseDown:self];
    } else {
        [self.delegate tagCloudExpandDown:self];
    }
}

//======================================================================
//PUBLIC METHODS
//======================================================================
//EXPAND
-(void)expand {
    [self modifyViewsForExpanding];
    [self setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:self.frame withX:nil y:nil width:nil height:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[WAControlsUtility getHeightOfView:self]]]];
    [self.btnToggleVisibility setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.btnToggleVisibility];
}
-(void)expandWithAnimation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
        [self expand];
    }];
}

//COLLAPSE
-(void)collapse {
    CGFloat height = [@" " sizeWithFont:[self tagFont]].height * 2.0 + 2;//plus 2 for the spacing between lines

    [self setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:self.frame withX:nil y:nil width:nil height:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:height]]];
    [self.btnToggleVisibility setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [self modifyViewsForCollapsing];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.btnToggleVisibility];
}
-(void)collapseWithAnimation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
        [self collapse];
    }];
}

//======================================================================
//UTILITY
//======================================================================
-(NSArray*)getCharacterArrayFromString:(NSString*)string {
    NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[string length]];
    for (int i=0; i < [string length]; i++) {
        NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string characterAtIndex:i]];
        [characters addObject:ichar];
    }
    return characters;
}
-(void)setColorOfSubviews {
    for(UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] == NO) {
            if(view != self.vExpand) {
                [view setBackgroundColor:self.tagColor];
            } else {
                [view setBackgroundColor:[self.tagColor colorWithAlphaComponent:.5]];
            }

        }
    }
}
-(void)clearTags {
    [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [self addSubview:self.btnToggleVisibility];
    [self addSubview:self.vExpand];
}

//EXPAND/COLLAPSE UTILITY
-(NSArray*)getNthRow:(int)nth {//starts at 1 //not zero based
    NSMutableArray *rowViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.subviews.count];

    CGFloat rowOrigin = [@" " sizeWithFont:self.tagFont].height * (nth - 1) + (nth - 1);
    for(UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if([view isEqual:self.btnToggleVisibility] || [view isEqual:self.vExpand]) {//ignore the button and expand view
            continue;
        }

        if(view.frame.origin.y == rowOrigin) {
            [rowViews addObject:view];
        }
    }

    return rowViews;
}
-(UIView*)getGreatestXOriginViewForNthRow:(int)nthRow {
    NSArray *rowViews = [self getNthRow:nthRow];
    UIView *greatestXOriginView = nil;

    for(UIView *view in rowViews) {
        if(greatestXOriginView == nil || view.frame.origin.x > greatestXOriginView.frame.origin.x ) {
            greatestXOriginView = view;
        }
    }
    return greatestXOriginView;
}
-(void)modifyViewsForCollapsing {
    if([self getNthRow:3].count == 0) {
        return;
    }
    UIView *greatestXOriginView = [self getGreatestXOriginViewForNthRow:2];

    //update the label and the container
    [self.lblExpand setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%d", self.dataTags.count - greatestXOriginView.tag]];
    [self.lblExpand setFont:self.tagFont];
    [self.lblExpand setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:self.lblExpand.frame withX:nil y:nil width:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.lblExpand.text sizeWithFont:self.tagFont].width] height:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:greatestXOriginView.frame.size.height]]];
    [self resizeLabelContainer];

    //figure out where to place the expand and how to size it and the last label on the row
    CGFloat viewXValue = (greatestXOriginView.frame.size.width + greatestXOriginView.frame.origin.x);
    CGFloat expandXValue = self.frame.size.width - self.vExpand.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat xOrigin;

    if(viewXValue < expandXValue - 1.0) {//will it all fit without modifying any existing views
        xOrigin = viewXValue + 1.0;
    } else {//shrink the last view 
        [greatestXOriginView setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:greatestXOriginView.frame withX:nil y:nil width:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:expandXValue - 1 - greatestXOriginView.frame.origin.x] height:nil]];
        for(UIView *view in greatestXOriginView.subviews) {//shrink the label
            [view setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:view.frame withX:nil y:nil width:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:greatestXOriginView.frame.size.width - 4.0] height:nil]];
        }

        if(greatestXOriginView.frame.size.width < 20.0) {
            [greatestXOriginView setAlpha:0.0];//hide the last view if it got shrank down a lot
        }
        xOrigin = expandXValue;
    }

    [self.vExpand setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:self.vExpand.frame withX:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:xOrigin] y:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:greatestXOriginView.frame.origin.y] width:nil height:nil]];
    [self.vExpand setAlpha:1.0];
    [self resizeLabelContainer];
}

-(void)modifyViewsForExpanding {
    UIView *view = [self getGreatestXOriginViewForNthRow:2];
    UILabel *label;
    if(view != nil) {
        label = (UILabel*)view.subviews[0];
        CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:self.tagFont];
        [label setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:label.frame withX:nil y:nil width:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:labelSize.width] height:nil]];
        [view setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:view.frame withX:nil y:nil width:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:labelSize.width + 4] height:nil]];
        [view setAlpha:1.0];
    }

    //hide expand
    [self.vExpand setAlpha:0.0];
}
-(void)resizeLabelContainer {
    [self.vExpand setFrame:[WAControlsUtility updateFrame:self.vExpand.frame withX:nil y:nil width:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.lblExpand.frame.size.width + 4.0] height:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.lblExpand.frame.size.height]]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `NSAttributedString` with the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` attribute. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: for iOS 5 compatibility: CATextLayer supports NSAttributedString

Comment: It doesn't look like NSBackgroundColorAttributeName is supported in iOS 5.